# How to share instances between Prototypes (Spring LoC)

Tags: java, spring, spring-ioc

To run a Job in a `TaskExecutor` I need to instantiate new Jobs implementing the `Runnable` Interface. To solve this, i will [create a new Spring Prototype Bean named Job "on Demand"](http://java.dzone.com/articles/creating-new-spring-beans).

But in my application a `Job` has two fields `LocationChanger` and `QueryTyper`. These two should share **the same `WebDriver` instance** created by a `WebDriverFactory`.

Now the question is how to design this with Spring?

[image: UML of the Architecture]

This is the related code:

```java
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class Job implements Runnable {

    @Autowired
    LocationChanger locationChanger;

    @Autowired
    QueryTyper queryTyper;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // at this point the locationChanger and
        // queryTyper should share the same instance
    }

}

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class LocationChanger {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(...) // For every new Job Created, the same WebDriver instance should be injected.
    WebDriver webDriver
}

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class QueryTyper {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(...) // For every new Job Created, the same WebDriver instance should be injected.
    WebDriver webDriver
}

public class WebDriverFactoryBean implements FactoryBean<WebDriver> {
    @Override
    public WebDriver getObject() throws Exception {
        return // createdAndPrepare...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot!

**Update 1:**
A possible solution could be to autowire the `WebDriver` in the Job **only** and then in a `@PostConstruct` inject this WebDriver to the `LocationChanger` and `QueryTyper`. But then i wire by hand.

```java
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class Job implements Runnable {

    @Autowired
    LocationChanger locationChanger;

    @Autowired
    QueryTyper queryTyper;

    @Autowired
    WebDriver webDriver;

    @PostConstruct
    public void autowireByHand() {
        locationChanger.setWebDriver(this.webDriver);
        queryTyper.setWebDriver(this.webDriver);
    }
}

// + remove all @Autowired WebDriver's from LocationChanger and QueryTyper
```

Comment: So you want `WebDriver` to be a singleton?

Comment: No, everytime if a `Job` is instantiated, this `Job` and it's childs should share the same `WebDriver`. So it's not Singleton :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your requirement, you need `WebDriver` to be shared between a `Job` and `LocationChanger`. So it's not `prototype` scope, and it's not `singleton` scope. To solve this, I think you either have to do it by hand, as you suggest, or you could try to implement your own scope, as described in the [Spring reference documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes)

**Edit**

I don't think you "handwired" solution looks that bad BTW.

Comment: Thanks for the idea of a custom Scope. Maybe that's the Way. I thought about dynamic Qualifiers. For Example: The `LocationChanger` and `QueryTyper` should mark the Webdriver like this: `@Autowire @Qualifier(Somehow Relate this String to the created Instance of Job) webDriver` annotation.

Comment: A custom scope should be possible. You just have to figure out where to store your instances for retrieval, and then correlate them with the "conversation id".